# Efficiency of using a Python list as a queue

Tags: python, list, memory-leaks

A coworker recently wrote a program in which he used a Python list as a queue.  In other words, he used `.append(x)` when needing to insert items and `.pop(0)` when needing to remove items.

I know that Python has [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) and I'm trying to figure out whether to spend my (limited) time to rewrite this code to use it.  Assuming that we perform millions of appends and pops but never have more than a few thousand entries, will his list usage be a problem?

In particular, will the underlying array used by the Python list implementation continue to grow indefinitely have millions of spots even though the list only has a thousand things, or will Python eventually do a `realloc` and free up some of that memory?

Comment: The underlying does NOT continue to grow indefinitely (only stays a little bigger than its "high-water mark"). But the O(N) vs O(1) issues highlighted in some answers can be important.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You won't run out of memory using the `list` implementation, but performance will be poor. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html):

> Though `list` objects support similar
>   operations, they are optimized for
>   fast fixed-length operations and incur
>   O(n) memory movement costs for
>   `pop(0)` and `insert(0, v)` operations
>   which change both the size and
>   position of the underlying data
>   representation.

So using a `deque` will be much faster.

Comment: "much faster"?  Or potentially faster?

Comment: For lists of size 1000, 10x. More than an order of magnitude is "much faster" in my book.

Comment: Lott: popping from a list is O(N), from a deque is O(1).

Comment: The original question was on garbage collection -- not speed.  Regarding speed, if the list stays short (under a dozen items), perhaps the **O**(*n*) issue isn't 10x.

Comment: CPython doesn't use garbage collection, it uses reference counting. Performance will be directly related to how often memory re-allocations are performed.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, switching to a deque shouldn't require a lot of work compared to, say, posting this question.

Comment: @John, you're very deeply wrong: CPython uses BOTH reference counting AND mark-and-sweep, generational garbage collection (which you can control to some extent via the gc module in the standard library). So "CPython doesn't use garbage collection" is a deeply flawed statement indeed.

Comment: @S.Lott, OP says "never more than a few thousands" and you think this translates to "under a dozen"?! Must be VERY small thousands indeed, what?-)

Comment: @Alex: The garbage collector in `gc` is optional, and might not be enabled; relying on its presence is a bad idea. Reference counting is the only memory management guaranteed to be present when running in CPython.

Comment: You might actually run out of memory using a list.  Deque's are allocated in buckets which do not have to be contiguous with each other, so basically you can create a deque as large as your available memory.  Lists, however, are arrays, and must be allocated contiguously, which you might find causing you some trouble if they get to be megabytes in size (and they may, at the very least, cause serious memory fragmentation due to reallocation).

Comment: @JohnMillikin: list.pop(n) is only O(n) for x=0. For popping off the end of the list, might it be approximately O(1) (like a deque.) If that's true, then using a list as a stack seems reasonable, but using it as a FIFO queue isn't.

Answer (score 85):

Some answers claimed a "10x" speed advantage for deque vs list-used-as-FIFO when both have 1000 entries, but that's a bit of an overbid:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'q=range(1000)' 'q.append(23); q.pop(0)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.24 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import collections; q=collections.deque(range(1000))' 'q.append(23); q.popleft()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.573 usec per loop
```

`python -mtimeit` is your friend -- a really useful and simple micro-benchmarking approach!  With it you can of course also trivially explore performance in much-smaller cases:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'q=range(100)' 'q.append(23); q.pop(0)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.972 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import collections; q=collections.deque(range(100))' 'q.append(23); q.popleft()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.576 usec per loop
```

(not very different for 12 instead of 100 items btw), and in much-larger ones:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'q=range(10000)' 'q.append(23); q.pop(0)'
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.81 usec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import collections; q=collections.deque(range(10000))' 'q.append(23); q.popleft()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.574 usec per loop
```

You can see that the claim of O(1) performance for deque is well founded, while a list is over twice as slow around 1,000 items, an order of magnitude around 10,000. You can also see that even in such cases you're only wasting 5 microseconds or so per append/pop pair and decide how significant that wastage is (though if that's all you're doing with that container, deque has no downside, so you might as well switch even if 5 usec more or less won't make an important difference).

Answer (score 22):

From Beazley's [*Python Essential Reference, Fourth Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329786), p. 194:

> Some library modules provide new types
>   that outperform the built-ins at
>   certain tasks. For instance,
>   collections.deque type provides
>   similar functionality to a list but
>   has been highly optimized for the
>   insertion of items at both ends. A
>   list, in contrast, is only efficient
>   when appending items at the end. If
>   you insert items at the front, all of
>   the other elements need to be shifted
>   in order to make room. The time
>   required to do this grows as the list
>   gets larger and larger. Just to give
>   you an idea of the difference, here is a timing measurement of inserting one million items at the front of a list and a deque:

And there follows this code sample:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('s.appendleft(37)', 'import collections; s = collections.deque()', number=1000000)
0.13162776274638258
>>> timeit('s.insert(0,37)', 's = []', number=1000000)
932.07849908298408
```

Timings are from my machine.

---

2012-07-01 Update

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> n = 1024 * 1024
>>> while n > 1:
...     print '-' * 30, n
...     timeit('s.appendleft(37)', 'import collections; s = collections.deque()', number=n)
...     timeit('s.insert(0,37)', 's = []', number=n)
...     n >>= 1
... 
------------------------------ 1048576
0.1239769458770752
799.2552740573883
------------------------------ 524288
0.06924104690551758
148.9747350215912
------------------------------ 262144
0.029170989990234375
35.077512979507446
------------------------------ 131072
0.013737916946411133
9.134140014648438
------------------------------ 65536
0.006711006164550781
1.8818109035491943
------------------------------ 32768
0.00327301025390625
0.48307204246520996
------------------------------ 16384
0.0016388893127441406
0.11021995544433594
------------------------------ 8192
0.0008249282836914062
0.028419017791748047
------------------------------ 4096
0.00044918060302734375
0.00740504264831543
------------------------------ 2048
0.00021195411682128906
0.0021741390228271484
------------------------------ 1024
0.00011205673217773438
0.0006101131439208984
------------------------------ 512
6.198883056640625e-05
0.00021386146545410156
------------------------------ 256
2.9087066650390625e-05
8.797645568847656e-05
------------------------------ 128
1.5974044799804688e-05
3.600120544433594e-05
------------------------------ 64
8.821487426757812e-06
1.9073486328125e-05
------------------------------ 32
5.0067901611328125e-06
1.0013580322265625e-05
------------------------------ 16
3.0994415283203125e-06
5.9604644775390625e-06
------------------------------ 8
3.0994415283203125e-06
5.0067901611328125e-06
------------------------------ 4
3.0994415283203125e-06
4.0531158447265625e-06
------------------------------ 2
2.1457672119140625e-06
2.86102294921875e-06
```

Answer (score 5):

Every `.pop(0)` takes N steps, since the list has to be reorganized. The required memory will not grow endlessly and only be as big as required for the items that are held.

I'd recommend using `deque` to get O(1) append and pop from front.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like a bit of empirical testing might be the best thing to do here - second order issues might make one approach better in practice, even if it's not better in theory.